# Displaying row/column of point in raster using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, pixel, column

Is it possible in QGIS to display the column and row index of pixel in raster?

I mean something similar to the value tool.

Comment: Several years later, this functionality is now available inside the [Value Tool plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/valuetool/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need to calculate the pixel coordinates in terms of row and column. For programming, it's necessary to know point coordinates and this raster information:  width, height, raster units per pixel x, raster units per pixel y, xmin and ymax extent. The snipped code in a QGIS plugin to do that it could be:

```
.
.
.

    def display_point(self, point, button):
        # report map coordinates from a canvas click
        coords = "{}, {}".format(point.x(), point.y())
        self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(str(coords))
        self.dlg.show()

        layer = self.wcb.currentLayer()

        if layer is not None:

            width = layer.width()
            height = layer.height()

            xsize = layer.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
            ysize = layer.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()

            extent = layer.extent()

            ymax = extent.yMaximum()
            xmin = extent.xMinimum()

            #row in pixel coordinates
            row = int(((ymax - point.y()) / ysize) + 1)

            #row in pixel coordinates
            column = int(((point.x() - xmin) / xsize) + 1)

            if row <= 0 or column <=0 or row > height or column > width:
                row = "out of extent"
                column = "out of extent"

        else:
            row = "no raster"
            column = "no raster"

        self.dlg.lineEdit_2.setText(str(row))

        self.dlg.lineEdit_3.setText(str(column))
.
.
.
```

It works well as you can see at next image:

[image]

If you have not experience in plugin programming, you can adapt above code to operate at Python Console of QGIS.

Without any programming, you can try this approach:

1) Get extent and raster resolution from Layer Properties.

[image]

2) Use this information (xinit_r, yinit_r, cell_size) at the attributes table of point vector layer (see below image). The x, y coordinates were obtained with geometry options of field calculator.

[image]

The values of **n_row** and **n_column** were also obtained by using the field calculator (see next images for equations):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, very interesting tools that should be integrated in Qgis. Did you publish this plugin and if not should it be possible to keep it available ?
Best

Answer (score 7):

You can use the ["Value Tool"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/valuetool/) plugin for QGIS.

[image: Value Tool plugin example]