# Getting row, col on click of a pixel on a QGIS map

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-python-console

I want to get the row, col coordinates of a raster I'm viewing in QGIS by clicking on a pixel. I found [Displaying row/column of point in raster using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166204), which presumably provides hints about how to go about this. However, I am unable to implement it successfully.

I think the appropriate route is to use the QGIS Python console--I don't care where or how the row, col coordinates are displayed as long as I can see it update as I click different pixels. I have been trying a variety of things all day, but haven't made much progress. My plan was to use the above-provided code, but I am having trouble getting QGIS to return the coordinates from a map-clicked pixel.

For example, I tried implementing the code at [Getting coordinates by clicking on QGIS Canvas with PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108044), but I am not even sure how to run it. I saved it as a separate py file, imported it in the QGIS console, but I am not sure how to run vector_selectbypoint from within the python console as it is a class.

Does anyone have any tips for how I should be approaching this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a rectified image, that is an image without rotation, or a regular raster, you may paste the following scripts into the Python console or execute them as script from the editor. Each of them outputs row and columns indices (0..x/y).

The first script is based on class QgsMapTool implementing `canvasPressEvent()` 
 method. It evaluates **clicks with the left mouse button**. Once executed the tool remains active until another map tool is activated.

For more details see this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45094/how-to-programatically-check-for-a-mouse-click-in-qgis?noredirect=1&lq=1).

```
from qgis.gui import QgsMapTool
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from math import floor

# references to QGIS objects 
canvas = iface.mapCanvas() 
layer = iface.activeLayer() 
data_provider = layer.dataProvider()

# properties to map mouse position to row/col index of the raster in memory 
extent = data_provider.extent() 
width = data_provider.xSize() if data_provider.capabilities() & data_provider.Size else 1000 
height = data_provider.ySize() if data_provider.capabilities() & data_provider.Size else 1000 
xres = extent.width() / width 
yres = extent.height() / height

class ClickTool(QgsMapTool): 
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        QgsMapTool.__init__(self, canvas)
        self.canvas = canvas 

    def canvasPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton: 
            x = event.pos().x()
            y = event.pos().y()

            # clicked position on screen to map coordinates
            point = self.canvas.getCoordinateTransform().toMapCoordinates(x, y)

            if extent.xMinimum() <= point.x() <= extent.xMaximum() and \
                extent.yMinimum() <= point.y() <= extent.yMaximum():
                col = int(floor((point.x() - extent.xMinimum()) / xres))
                row = int(floor((extent.yMaximum() - point.y()) / yres))

                print row, col

tool = ClickTool(iface.mapCanvas())
iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(tool)
```

The second script will output the row and column index of the raster below the current cursor position, and **is updated while the cursor is moving**. When the cursor is outside the extend of the raster, then nothing is printed.

```
from math import floor

# references to QGIS objects 
canvas = iface.mapCanvas() 
layer = iface.activeLayer() 
data_provider = layer.dataProvider()

# properties to map mouse position to row/col index of the raster in memory 
extent = data_provider.extent() 
width = data_provider.xSize() if data_provider.capabilities() & data_provider.Size else 1000 
height = data_provider.ySize() if data_provider.capabilities() & data_provider.Size else 1000 
xres = extent.width() / width 
yres = extent.height() / height

# slot called whenever mouse position changes 
def show_raster_row_col(point):
    if extent.xMinimum() <= point.x() <= extent.xMaximum() and \
        extent.yMinimum() <= point.y() <= extent.yMaximum():
        col = int(floor((point.x() - extent.xMinimum()) / xres))
        row = int(floor((extent.yMaximum() - point.y()) / yres))

        # output row and column index to console
        print row, col

# connect slot to canvas signal
canvas.xyCoordinates.connect(show_raster_row_col)
```

To stop the script, type the following line into the console:

```
canvas.xyCoordinates.disconnect(show_raster_row_col)
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, but have you used this? It continually outputs coordinates, even when I move my mouse off the screen. I cannot read them because the list is updated so frequently. In my question, I request the coordinates to be output on clicking--do you know the commands for that? If not, this is at least a better jumping-off point for me.

Comment: I should also note that I needed to put the xres and yres commands on separate lines to avoid a Syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @Detlev. I needed to replace your first two lines with these: from qgis.gui import QgsMapTool; 
from PyQt4.QtCore import QPoint, Qt. Otherwise Qt could not be found in qgis.gui and QgsMapTool was undefined. But now it works and I have a template for future modifications! I'm running QGIS 2.14.2 FWIW.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I obviously copied wrong lines into the editor widget here.

Comment: To get this working in QGIS 3 (which uses Python 3), all you need to do is change `print(row, col)` to `print(f'{row}, {col}')`.

Comment: I get the following error when trying to run the first script, if anybody can help:

name 'iface' is not defined See log for more details